# How to align two elements from innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I thought  `span` would align the elements, but the button appears under the p-element.

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  main.innerHTML += `
  <span>
    <p onclick="border(${i})">${arr[i].name}</p>
    <button>Delete</button>
  </span>`
}
```

Comment: `p` is a block element, and is invalid to be a child of a `span`. It also means that anything placed after it will be pushed to the next line.

Comment: this is a normal behaviour <p> is a paragraph that means when it is printed what is coming next is going to be in a new line.
try inserting your button inside your p
<p> text <button></button> </p>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***`p`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) element is a [*Block-level element*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), you can set the *display* property to `inline-block`.

**Demo:**

```js
var arr = [{name: "test"}]
var main = document.getElementById("main");
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  main.innerHTML += `
  <span>
    <p onclick="border(${i})" style="display:inline-block">${arr[i].name}</p>
    <button>Delete</button>
  </span>`;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have `p` and `button` inline just swap `p` with `span` as I made below. 
You can also check my snipet

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let main = document.querySelector('body');
  let arr = [{name: 'first'},{name: 'second'}];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       main.innerHTML += `
                  <p>
                  <span onclick="border(${i})">${arr[i].name}</span>
                  <button>Delete</button>
                  </p>
                  `;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body> 
</body>
</html>
```